# how to extract the first number from each string in a vector in R?

Tags: regex, r, vector

I am new to regex in R. Here I have a vector where I am interested in extracting the first occurance of a number in each string of the vector .

I have a vector called "shootsummary" which looks like this.

```
> head(shootsummary)
[1] Aaron Alexis, 34, a military veteran and contractor from Texas, opened fire in the Navy installation, killing 12 people and wounding 8 before being shot dead by police.                                         
[2] Pedro Vargas, 42, set fire to his apartment, killed six people in the complex, and held another two hostages at gunpoint before a SWAT team stormed the building and fatally shot him.                           
[3] John Zawahri, 23, armed with a homemade assault rifle and high-capacity magazines, killed his brother and father at home and then headed to Santa Monica College, where he was eventually killed by police.      
[4] Dennis Clark III, 27, shot and killed his girlfriend in their shared apartment, and then shot two witnesses in the building's parking lot and a third victim in another apartment, before being killed by police.
[5] Kurt Myers, 64, shot six people in neighboring towns, killing two in a barbershop and two at a car care business, before being killed by officers in a shootout after a nearly 19-hour standoff.
```

The first occurance of a number in each string denotes 'age' of the individual and I am interested in extracting ages from these strings without mixing them with other numbers in the lines listed .

I used:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", shootsummary))
```

It resulted in :

```
[1]  34128     42     23     27   6419
```

I am looking for a result that looks like this with just the ages extracted from the sentence without extracting other numbers that occur after the age.

```
[1]  34     42     23     27   64
```

Comment: Suppose one of the vector elements doesn't have number, what would you want to return.  In my solution, it returns `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below `sub` command,

```
> test
[1] "Aaron Alexis, 34, a military veteran and contractor from Texas, opened fire in the Navy installation, killing 12 people and wounding 8 before being shot dead by police."              
[2] "Pedro Vargas, 42, set fire to his apartment, killed six people in the complex, and held another two hostages at gunpoint before a SWAT team stormed the building and fatally shot him."
> sub("^\\D*(\\d+).*$", "\\1", test)
[1] "34" "42"
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `^` asserts that we are at the start of a line.
- `\D*` Matches zero or more non-digit characters.
- `(\d+)` then the following one or more digits is captured into group 1(*first number*).
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of a line.
- Finally all the matched chars are replaced by the chars which are present inside the first group .

Comment: thanks avinash, it worked like a charm..since I am new to regex, could you please help me get a clearer idea of what you did here. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`stringi` would be faster

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first(shootsummary, regex="\\d+")
#[1] "34" "42" "23" "27" "64"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, I installed'stringi' and successfully run the code. thanks for the early response.

Answer (score 2):

One option is `str_extract` from `stringr` with an `as.numeric` wrap.

```
> library(stringr)
> as.numeric(str_extract(shootsummary, "[0-9]+"))
# [1] 34 42 23 27 64
```

**Update** In response to your question in the comments of this answer, here's a little explanation.  The full explanation of a function can be found in its help file.

- `str_extract` returns the first occurrence of the regular expression.  It is vectorized over the character vector in its first argument.
- The regular expression `[0-9]+` matches any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
- `as.numeric` changes the resulting character vector into a numeric vector.

Comment: Thanks Richard, your code worked too, may I know how went abt it ? I am totally new to regex, I am familiar with very basic and simple code in regex..thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for showing it in stringr, i always wanted to use stringr , you helped me start using it :)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
splitbycomma <- strsplit(shootsummary, ",")
as.numeric(  sapply(splitbycomma, "[", 2)  )
```

Comment: I guess I did not get something right here.. the first line itself did not run for me,, let me tweak it n get back.. thanks berry..

Answer (score 1):

R's `regmatches()` method returns a vector with the first regex match in each element:

```
regmatches(shootsummary, regexpr("\\d+", shootsummary, perl=TRUE));
```

Comment: hey Tim, thanks. This seems a simpler use of R's power of packages n functions.. but it returned it as a string .. but still..that was useful..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`:

```
test <- ("xff 34 sfsdg 352 efsrg")

sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", test)
# [1] "34"
```

*How does the regex work?*

The `.` matches any character. The quantifier `*` means any number of occurrences. The `?` is used to match all characters up to the first match of `\\d` (digits). The quantifier `+` means one or multiple occurrences. The brackets around `\\d` are the first match group. This may be followed by additional characters (`.*`). The second argument (`\\1`) replaces the whole string with the first match group (i.e., the first number).

Comment: Thanks Sven, your code and avinash's code r lill similar, I am curious how you got to this, i would like to understand the underlying concept.. i am new to regex , thanks in advance

Comment: @user3563667 I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very nicely with the `str_first_number()` function from the `strex` package, or for more general needs, there's the `str_nth_number()` function.

```r
pacman::p_load(strex)
shootsummary <- c("Aaron Alexis, 34, a military veteran and contractor ...",
                  "Pedro Vargas, 42, set fire to his apartment, killed six ...",
                  "John Zawahri, 23, armed with a homemade assault rifle ...",
                  "John Zawahri, 23, armed with a homemade assault rifle ...",
                  "Dennis Clark III, 27, shot and killed his girlfriend ...",
                  "Kurt Myers, 64, shot six people in neighboring ..."
)
str_first_number(shootsummary)
#> [1] 34 42 23 23 27 64
str_nth_number(shootsummary, n = 1)
#> [1] 34 42 23 23 27 64
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).