# Extract integer from powershell string

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to extract a number from a string, the number changes all the time so cannot just be hard coded eg:

```
some random amount of text 54321 more text and another number 123
```

I know I can use something like:

```
'john123456smith' -replace "[^0-9]" , ''
```

but that gives me `54321123` which is not what I want, I only want the `54321`.

Any idea on a regular expression that will do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25885361/2634547

Your answer is in above thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of places the number should have (here 5)

```
$String = "john123456smith"
If ($String -match '^\D*(\d{5}).*$') {
    "Foud number {0}" -f $Matches[1]
} else {
    "no number with 5 places found"
}
```

Sample output:

```
Foud number 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on your description, this should work:

```
$test = 'asdfasdfasdfadf54321asdfasdfasdf123'
$test -match '[^0-9]+([0-9]+)'
$matches[1]
```